# Why register clearing is done prior to setting a new value

Tags: pic

As beginner in PIC programming under ASM I do not understand why in the examples a register is cleared prior to setting a new value. In an actual running programm this is not done and everything works fine.

Example with CRLF

```
CRLF  PORTB        ; Init PORTB by clearing output data latches
BSF   STATUS, RP0  ; Select Bank 1
MOVLW 0xCF         ; Value used to initialize data direction
MOVWF TRISB        ; Set RB<3:0> as inputs
                   ; RB<5-4> as outputs
                   ; RB <7-6> as inputs
```

Example without CRLF

```
BSF   STATUS, RP0  ; Select Bank 1
MOVLW 0xCF         ; Value used to initialize data direction
MOVWF TRISB        ; Set RB<3:0> as inputs
                   ; RB<5-4> as outputs
                   ; RB <7-6> as inputs
```

Both parts work fine so why to clear?

Comment: Your first example contains no instances of a "register cleared prior to setting a new value" - PORTB and TRISB are entirely separate registers.  The problem with the second example is that the initial state of the two output pins was never specified; if they are connected to something with physical consequences (like a motor), you'd have no idea what your code would do at startup.

Comment: @jasonharper
  
If I understand this well then CRLF PORTB clears the data in the latches while TRISB changes the properties of PORTB?

Answer (score 0):

A common pitfall with microchip controllers is writing to the PORTx registers. You should **never** do this. If you want to change the state of output pins, you should write directly to the output latches (LATx). This is because writing to the PORTx registers involves a read/modify/write process that can cause issues if pins are changing state at the same time. Use PORTx only to read the values of input pins (and, of course, output pins).

As has been mentioned in comments, the TRISx registers set the direction of pins (0= output, 1=input). Note that this is opposite to the settings for some other processors (e.g. Motorola HC12) which use 0=input, 1=output.

Comment: Are you suggesting not to use  CRLF PORTX. during init. But to use TRISX first and then write the clear instruction to the port in question.?